# How to line break between two cell's values

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to accomplish a line break formula based off two cell's values. More specifically, `CONTINGENCY` and `END`. So an example would be something like this:
`

### CONTINGENCY 'XXX'

### DISCONNECT BUS 1

### DISCONNECT BUS 2

### DISCONNECT BUS 3

### DISCONNECT BUS 4

END
-------------------   `

---

My desired output would like to be this

`CONTINGENCY 'XXX'
 DISCONNECT BUS 1
 DISCONNECT BUS 2
 DISCONNECT BUS 3
 DISCONNECT BUS 4
END`

where it is merged into one cell between the `contingency` and `end`.

[image: SAMPLE OUTPUT]

Also i have to do it for 10000 lines of code. Should i put an identifer or something, like a unique ID number for the `contingency`? Open to any suggestions or solutions.

So i used wrap texting and using CHAR (10) for line breaking but can't figure out a code for specific cell values or identifiers.

`=C2&Q&C3&Q&C4&Q&C5&Q&C6&Q&C7`  where `Q=CHAR(10)`

Comment: You can use [`Range.FindNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) for this.

Comment: If you have the latest version of Excel, `TextJoin` should do it [see here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c&ved=2ahUKEwjD1ZLowsLjAhWU6XMBHaBzA6EQFjADegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2DufLN3a6YkiFuUH24fOtR&cshid=1563592310762)

Comment: Please add a sample screenshot to give an idea, WHERE your two (or seven?) cells are located typically and where the desired output should be shown.

Comment: @Asger I have posted the sample output in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code loops over all rows, identifies the rows with "CONTINGENCY" and concatenates the non-empty cell values there.

```
Private Sub ConcatCells()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim currentRow As Long, concatRow As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim WithinBlock As Boolean

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Whatever")

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        For currentRow = 1 To lastRow

            If Left(.Cells(currentRow, "C").Value, 11) = "CONTINGENCY" Then
                WithinBlock = True
                concatRow = currentRow
                .Cells(concatRow, "D").Value = .Cells(currentRow, "C").Value

            ElseIf Left(.Cells(currentRow, "C").Value, 3) = "END" Then
                WithinBlock = False
                .Cells(concatRow, "D").Value = _
                    .Cells(concatRow, "D").Value & vbLf & _
                    .Cells(currentRow, "C").Value

            ElseIf WithinBlock And .Cells(currentRow, "C").Value <> "" Then
                .Cells(concatRow, "D").Value = _
                    .Cells(concatRow, "D").Value & vbLf & _
                    .Cells(currentRow, "C").Value

            End If
        Next currentRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I found my fault. I just added a marker, which is set, while the currentRow-counter is "within a block" of to-be-concatenated-cells.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code in the Example and manipulate it for your use:

**Like:**

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("c1:c10000") 'Change the worksheet & Range
     Set c = .Find("Contingency", lookin:=xlValues) 'change the lookup text 
     If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
             c.Value = 5 ' Put your concatenate code here instead of this line
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        If c is Nothing Then
            GoTo DoneFinding
        End If
        Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
      End If
      DoneFinding:
End With
```

Taken from: [Range.FindNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext)

Comment: What would be on my concatatente code and i keep getting invalid outside procedure compile error